# Sandbox Logging dll won't load

Tags: sharepoint-online, sandbox-solution, logging

I am trying to use the [codeplex.spsl Sandbox Logging framework](http://spsl.codeplex.com/releases/view/67515) but am having trouble getting it to execute in my code.

The following error occurs on the last line of the following code snippet.

Getting Error Message for Exception System.InvalidOperationException: Error activating type from sandboxed code assembly. The cached sandboxed assembly could not be found.

```
using System;
using System.Security.Permissions;
using Microsoft.SharePoint;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Utilities;
using Microsoft.SharePoint.Workflow;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

using codeplex.spsl;

namespace SPOnline_EngineeringSiteAutomations.ProjectDocLib_EvntRcvr
{
    /// <summary>
    /// List Item Events
    /// </summary>
    public class ProjectDocLib_EvntRcvr : SPItemEventReceiver
    {
        static readonly string CONTRACTOR_FOLDER_NAME = "Contractor Folder";
        static readonly string CONTRACTOR_SEC_GROUP_NAME = "Contractors";

        /// <summary>
        /// An item was added.
        /// </summary>
        public override void ItemAdded(SPItemEventProperties properties)
        {
            // Logging Tool won't work!
            // This line prevents the event from firing!
            // If I comment it out then the event fires.
            Logging logger = new Logging(this.GetType());
```

This solution is suppose to be perfect for SharePoint online but since I cannot load dlls into the cloud GAC how is this tool suppose to work.  Thanks for reading and I look forward to your ideas.